# Extract names from a text

Tags: vba, excel, substring, extract

This is a sample data contained in one cell:

> 2014/08/19 12:59 John Doe 
>   add sample@hotmail.com

I need to extract the name in the text. I know that it is always placed after the datetime stamp.

My idea is to find the position of ":" and add 4 thus getting the position of the first letter of the first name:

```
colonLoc = InStr(sampleData, ":")
firstLetterLoc = colonLoc + 4
```

How can I get the first and last name after that?

Comment: will you have "add" after the last name always?

Comment: No. Succeeding text after the name can vary. @SiddharthRout

Comment: Can you confirm one last thing

Comment: Will there be a middle name or there will ALWAYS be a First Name and Last Name?

Comment: There will always be a First Name and Last Name. Can't say if there will sometimes be a middle name as all the samples I've seen don't include it. @SiddharthRout

Comment: In that case @Joshpbarron's answer will do what you want :) I have edited his answer.

Comment: Sorry have one more question. Will there ALWAYS be 2 Words after the last name?

Comment: No, it really varies @SiddharthRout

Comment: This makes it really difficult then... How would one ascertain where the name ends?

Comment: For example `2014/08/19 12:59 Kate B Blah Blah Blah sample@hotmail.com` And we want to extract only "Kate B"

Comment: I edited the sample data. After the name, the succeeding text are in a new line. I forgot to fix it earlier. Still in one cell, but in a new line. @SiddharthRout

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot. I chose his answer because it worked with my other data and it can handle long firstnames. (Katherine May Ann) @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works even for names with spaces:

```
Function ExtractName(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim splitStr() As String
    Dim nameParts() As String
    splitStr = Split(str, " ")
    ReDim nameParts(LBound(splitStr) To UBound(splitStr) - 4)
    For i = LBound(nameParts) To UBound(nameParts)
        nameParts(i) = splitStr(i + 2)
    Next i
    ExtractName = Join(nameParts, " ")
End Function
```

What this effectively does is remove four substrings: the date, the time, the `add` bit, and the e-mail address. Everything else in the middle is assumed to be part of the name.

Example usage:

```
Debug.Print ExtractName("2014/08/19 12:59 John Doe add sample@hotmail.com")
Debug.Print ExtractName("2014/08/19 12:59 Johan Sebastian Bach add sample@hotmail.com")
Debug.Print ExtractName("2014/08/19 12:59 Fuh Wei Guo Tang add sample@hotmail.com")
Debug.Print ExtractName("2014/08/19 12:59 Jens von dem Hagen add sample@hotmail.com")
Debug.Print ExtractName("2014/08/19 12:59 José Manuel de Santiago Itthuralde add sample@hotmail.com")
```

**EDIT** Now you say your input string is split over two lines... This works for me with the input you specify:

```
Function ExtractName(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim splitStr() As String
    Dim nameParts() As String
    splitStr = Split(Split(str, vbLf)(0), " ")
    ReDim nameParts(LBound(splitStr) To UBound(splitStr) - 2)
    For i = LBound(nameParts) To UBound(nameParts)
        nameParts(i) = splitStr(i + 2)
    Next i
    ExtractName = Join(nameParts, " ")
End Function
```

Comment: As per OP's lastest comment, it is not necessary that there will be 2 words after the last name... so your code will not be able to handle For example `2014/08/19 12:59 Kate B Blah Blah Blah sample@hotmail.com` And we want to extract only "Kate B"

Comment: Right... it's always difficult to answer ever-changing questions!

Comment: BTW, do you want me to add an answer or will you edit your answer to update what OP mentioned? OP has updated the question to reflect that the rest of the data is in 2nd line... so perhaps using split with VBNewline as a parameter...

Comment: lol... Here is a one liner which may help? `Debug.Print Mid(Split(Split(Range("A1").Value, Chr(10))(0), ":")(1), 3)`

Comment: Right, well, I just edited my existing approach, even though it's overkill for this new problem definition!! :-/

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I'm sorry my question wasn't clear in the beginning. Again, thanks to you both. @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 6):

Here is a one liner to achieve what you want.

```
debug.print Mid(Split(Split(Range("A1").Value, Chr(10))(0), ":")(1), 3)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Actually you don't need VBA for this. You can use Excel formulas as well

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+3,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-(FIND(":",A1)+3))
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to remove your comment from your answer... Let the people choose the best answer — clearly yours given the updated question!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I really meant it. I really do not want this to be selected as an answer. :)

Comment: I'm afraid it's out of your hands :-)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Yeah it is :) Actually I didn't want to post an answer and hence I suggested the above under your answer but then when you ignored it, I had to :(

Comment: +1 was going to use a regexp - but formula is better

Comment: @brettdj: I was working on that angle too but then realized that it would be an overkill :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sampleData = "2014/08/19 12:59 John Doe add sample@hotmail.com"

New_String = Split(sampleData)

sName = New_String(2) & " " & New_String(3)

Debug.Print sName
```

Easy as that :)

Comment: Doesn't compile. Fails for names containing spaces e.g. Johan Sebastian de Groot.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: as per op, there is only first name and last name and no middle name :)

Comment: + 1 As per OP there is no middle name and hence this will work.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: `de Groot` is not a middle name!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I meant You will not have cases like `Johan Sebastian de Groot` You will have `Johan Groot` or `Johan Sebastian` or something like that. Only two words. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: No! `de Groot` and `von dem Hagen` are last names! Including the spaces. Nobody is called `Johan Groot` but there are very many `Johan de Groot`. `de` isn't the middle name.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: I agree with you. I was just saying that as per op (see comment below the question) there will not be more than 2 words in a name :) Based on what OP said josh's answer is technically correct:)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: If you read carefully, OP did *not* say there will not be more than 2 words in a name, but rather that there will always be a first name and last name — both of which can, in fact, contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It's like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Playground()
    Const SampleData As String = "2014/08/19 12:59 John Doe add sample@hotmail.com"
    Dim Parts() As String
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim LastName As String

    Parts = Split(SampleData)
    FirstName = Parts(2)
    LastName = Parts(3)

    Debug.Print FirstName
    Debug.Print LastName
End Sub
```

For more complicated cases (e.g. spaces in names) you might have to tweak it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you firstname (assuming there is only 1), lastname (all other names) and email in a variant array

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Name(source As String) As Variant
    Dim breakup As Variant

    breakup = Split(source, ":")
    breakup = Split(Mid(breakup(1), 4), " ")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FirstName As String
    FirstName = breakup(0)

    Dim LastName As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(breakup) - 2
        LastName = LastName & " " & breakup(i)
    Next
    LastName = Mid(LastName, 2)

    Dim Email As String
    Email = breakup(UBound(breakup))

    Name = Array(FirstName, LastName, Email)
End Function
```